# DISQUS.reset with ajax slideshow from sql query

Tags: sql, ajax, disqus

The code listed below is a reset function from DISQUS comments to allow it to work within an ajax website. I am trying to use the comments alongside a slideshow of images pulled from the sql. `$my_indentifier` is a changing value which links to the image being displayed.  When the next image is displayed I want the `onclick` function to reset the DISQUS comments. So each comments area is specific to each image. Can anybody help or suggest another system or method to do what i want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    reset = '<?php echo $my_identifier; ?>';
    var reset = function(){

        DISQUS.reset({
          reload: true,
          config: function () {
            this.page.identifier = '<?php echo $my_identifier; ?>';
            this.page.url = 'http://example.com/#!<?php echo $my_identifier; ?>';

          }
        });
    };

    </script>
<button onclick=reset();>Reload Disqus 1</button>    
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
             // required: replace example with your forum shortname

        var disqus_shortname = 'example';
        var disqus_identifier = 'newidentifier';




        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
```

I have tried many variations. I would prefer all this to be done on the fly when each image is brought in using ajax but the button method is the closest I have got to success.

Many thanks

Comment: Having the same problem. and I tried this implementation and it didn't get me very far.  Did you solve this?